# Turn by turn navigation for truck routes using Here Map sdk

Tags: flutter, heremap-navigation

I am having a truck route coordinates in backend.I passed those coordinates as a list of waypoint in 'calculateTruckRoute' method given in navigate edition sdk, but I am getting errors like -

1. visual-navigator - Maneuver geometry not doesn't contain enough coordinates.
2. visual-navigator - Unable to generate maneuver arrow polyline

Please help me to get a solution and resolve these errors.